# ZeroMQ compilation fails with gcc/g++ on windows

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, zeromq

I have 2 programs communicationg with each other: "server" written in GO running on Linux and "client" in c++ on Windows.

I have 3 files:
zmq.h
libzmq-v120-mt-4_0_4.lib
libzmq-v120-mt-4_0_4.dll

The client is an example from http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:hwclient and it compiles fine on linux with command line:

```
g++ zmq.h client.cpp -lzmq
```

I can compile the program on Windows with architecture x64 using Visual Studio and linking the *.lib file. Still, to run the program I need the *.dll file to be in the output directory, but that's ok.

The problem is that I don't want to use Visual Studio IDE and use gcc or g++ instead. No matter what I try I always get these errors

```
C:\..\client>g++ zmq.h main.cpp -L libzmq-v120-mt-4_0_4.lib
..\ccQafArl.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `__imp_zmq_ctx_new'
..\ccQafArl.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `__imp_zmq_socket'
..\ccQafArl.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `__imp_zmq_connect'
..\ccQafArl.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `__imp_zmq_send'
..\ccQafArl.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `__imp_zmq_recv'
..\ccQafArl.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `__imp_zmq_close'
..\ccQafArl.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `__imp_zmq_ctx_destroy'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It looks like g++ can't find the *.lib file but then how does VS compile with no errors? I have tried TDM-GCC-32, TDM-GCC-64 and and mingw64 g++ every time with the same result. ZeroMQ is installed  with windows installer, not from source.

How can I make it to compile on Windows without using Visual Studio?

Comment: Although this is MS-Windows and not Linux, I'm pretty sure that the `-L` option doesn't do what you think it does. If you read the documentation for the MS-Windows port of gcc, what does it tell you about the `-L` option?

Comment: You have to compile the `.lib` file with g++ also; you cannot link code compiled with g++ to a library compiled by MSVC. The file formats are different

Comment: Furthermore , if the the DLL was compiled by MSVC it may be using a different ABI to  g++. The proper way to go is to rebuild the DLL from source using g++

Comment: I thought so but I was hoping it will not be necessary. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you link libraries.

Firstly, you're using `-L`, which specifies a library search path, not a library.

You're looking for `-l`, and this takes a *name*, not a filename.

So:

```
-l lzmq-v120-mt-4_0_4
```

The linker should automatically search for matching files with the proper prefix and the proper extension for that platform (`.so`, `.a`, `.lib`, whatever).

(You got this right in the previous example.)

Have a little read of [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

Comment: Ok, I realized it just a moment ago, but with "gcc zmq.h main.cpp -L . -l libzmq-v120-mt-4_0_4" I got a new error : libzmq-v120-mt-4_0_4.lib: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status